# Django ORM inputting List of List with unequal amount of elements

Tags: python, django, list, django-models, django-orm

I have a list of lists, that looks as such:

major_list = [['element 1', 'element 2', 'element 3'],['element 1' 'element 2' 'element 3', 'element 4']]

I have created a table in models for I would like to have access to Django ORM that looks as such:

```
class Reviews(models.Model):
    element1 = models.CharField(max_length=400, default='')
    element2 = models.CharField(max_length=400, default='')
    element3 = models.CharField(max_length=400, default='')
    element4 = models.CharField(max_length=400, default='')
```

I am attempting to add these two list to the table using a for loop structured as:

```
for y in major_list:
    reviewz = StudentReviews(element1=y[0],
                             element2=y[1],
                             element3=y[2],
                             element4=y[3])
    reviewz.save()
```

Knowing that my list are different lengths, I would assume the instances where the list does not include an element4, would just fill as the default value, in this case: ' '. But I am getting the error saying my list index is out of range. Which makes sense, but I thought the default value would take over.

Does anyone have any ideas/help. I can clarify more if this comes off as confusing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The first element of `major_list` has only 3 elements, so `y[3]` will always trigger the exception. As a workaround, you can create a dictionary for each array, with each key having the value of each item. You can then pass it as an argument to instance a new object of your model using the `**` operator.

```
major_list = [['element 1', 'element 2', 'element 3'],['element 1', 'element 2', 'element 3', 'element 4']]

# for each element of the array
for i in range(0, len(major_list)):
    # we create a dictionary
    d = dict()
    # for each item of the array
    for j in range(0, len(major_list[i])):
        # we create a key representing which field in database. notice that j is incremented to match element1, element2.....
        k = 'element' + str(j + 1)
        # we set the value of they
        d[k] = major_list[i][j]
        # we create a reviewz object using the dict
        reviewz = StudentReviews(**d)
        # we save the reviews object
        reviewz.save()
```

**UPDATE**

In case your model fields names do not follow a specific pattern, it's better to work with dictionaries as you can use them directly to create and save new instances of the model. Each key represents a field, and you don't need to set all the keys, only the required ones.

```
items = [
    {
        'first_name': 'John',
        'last_name': 'Doe',
        'birth_date': datetime.now()
    },

    {
        'first_name': 'John',
        'last_name': 'Doe',
        'birth_date': datetime.now()    
    },

    {
        'first_name': 'John',
        'last_name': 'Doe',
        'birth_date': datetime.now()
    }
]

for item in items:
    reviewz = StudentReviews(**item)
    reviewz.save()
```

Comment: My question is an abbreviated version, say in your, k = 'element' + str(j + 1), I have other elements in the list, i.e Dates, how would you work around this?

Comment: If i am not hardcoding the values, so I gathered them from the scrape, how would you second answer be inputted?